# Display a fraction in one UILabel

Tags: swift, uilabel, fractions

I am trying to display a fraction as something like 1/2 but I want to line to be horizontal so the fraction looks more fraction like, some thing like this:

```
1
_
2
```

However with no massive space and in a way that I can use it inside one UILabel (which can have multiple lines). I also need to be able to put a fraction as the numerator/denominator of a fraction and so on. Any suggestions? (Fonts, characters...)

Thank you,
Gleb Koval

Comment: Make it two lines `"1\n2"` and underline the first line.

Comment: @Sulthan How can I underline one of the characters but not the other?

Comment: Using `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: @Sulthan Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a `UIView` subclass that draws a fraction:

```
class FractionView: UIView {
    var font: UIFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16) {
        didSet { self.setNeedsDisplay() }
    }
    var numerator: Int = 1 {
        didSet { self.setNeedsDisplay() }
    }
    var denominator: Int = 2{
        didSet { self.setNeedsDisplay() }
    }
    var spacing: CGFloat = 5{
        didSet { self.setNeedsDisplay() }
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let numString = "\(numerator)" as NSString
        let numWidth = numString.size(withAttributes: [.font: font]).width
        let denomString = "\(denominator)" as NSString
        let denomWidth = denomString.size(withAttributes: [.font: font]).width
        let numX: CGFloat
        let denomX: CGFloat

        if numWidth <= denomWidth {
            denomX = 0
            numX = (denomWidth - numWidth) / 2
        } else {
            denomX = (numWidth - denomWidth) / 2
            numX = 0
        }

        numString.draw(at: CGPoint(x: numX, y: 0), withAttributes: [.font : font])
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: font.lineHeight + spacing))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.maxX, y: font.lineHeight + spacing))
        UIColor.black.setStroke()
        path.lineWidth = 1
        path.stroke()
        denomString.draw(at: CGPoint(x: denomX, y: font.lineHeight + spacing * 2), withAttributes: [.font: font])
    }
}

// usage:
let width = ("12" as NSString).size(withAttributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)]).width
let view = FractionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: 48))
view.backgroundColor = .white
view.denominator = 12
```

[image]

As Sulthan in comments has suggested, using an `NSAttributedString` would be an easier approach:

```
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "1", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle : 1])
attrString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n2"))
attrString
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
label.attributedText = attrString
label.numberOfLines = 2
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but @Sulthan already made an answer in the comments which I am able to work with a lot easier

Comment: I didn't post an anwer because I was worried the number won't look every good with just underline. Probably some spaces will be needed to increase the size. Also the label will have to be centered. I would personally just use two labels with a simple view between them, with a given background.

Comment: @GlebKoval By the way, for Sulthan's approach to work for fractions with different number of digits, you need to add spaces.

Comment: @GlebKoval I updated the answer to make it work for fractions like `1/12`.

Comment: @Sweeper I got it to work by doing str = NSMutableAttributedString(string: “ 12 \n23”) and then all the underline code. In the string the spaces are invisible characters created using Alt + Space (on macs / iPads)

Comment: @Sweeper Sorry, I did this: `attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle, value: 1, range: NSMakeRange(0, 2))`

Comment: @Sulthan The fraction look very good when the font is "Courier"

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use Swift [FractionFormatter](https://swiftpackageregistry.com/davidwkeith/FractionFormatter). I wrote it to create fractions using Unicode fraction glyphs, so they look like "½" rather than having the numbers completely on top of each other. Since they are created from standard font glyphs, they can be used anywhere text is used.

```
let fractionFormatter = FractionFormatter()
fractionFormatter.string(from: 1.5) // "1 ½"
```

Comment: It is important to point out in an answer like this that the link is to your own 3rd party library. This borderlines on SPAM. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion